# Howto add geom-smooth to autoplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have this data

```
  ds <- as.data.frame(replicate(6, rnorm(100)))
  ds <- ts(ds, start = 1990, frequency = 4)
  colnames(ds) <- paste0("Variable", sep = "_", 1:ncol(ds))
  autoplot(ds, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

I want to add the +geom_smooth(method = "loess")
but i got this error

```
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, convert to `xts`

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
ds1 <- as.xts(ds)
autoplot(ds1) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Great! thanks . please last thing: I tried also: autoplot(strucchange::breakpoints(ds ~ 1)) but did not work.

Comment: @bicton The output of `breakpoints` is diffferent.  Please check `strucchange::breakpoints(ds ~ 1)`

Comment: Is there way to use autoplot with strucchange::breakpoints?

Comment: @bicton Can you post that as a new question as it is different from the one you posted. thanks

Comment: @bicton if you wanted to plot, you may check [here](https://datascienceplus.com/structural-changes-in-global-warming/), but that doesn't use `autoplot`

Comment: thanks. are you using Rstudio? It is strange i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @bicton i tested on R console

Comment: Itried even R but still the errore is there:> rlang::last_error()
Backtrace:
  1. (function (x, ...) ...
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_statistic(d, layout))
  6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
  7. l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
  8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
  9. self$stat$compute_layer(data, self$computed_stat_params, layout)
 10. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 11. ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: @bicton I am guessing that this would be related to your package versions